# xampp windows mariadb not starting

Tags: windows, mariadb, bitnami

mariaDB is not starting in my windows 10.

I am getting the following in the logs:

```
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5c8f)
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-12-19  9:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 42992145; transaction id 110929
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191219  9:18:14
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2019-12-19  9:18:14 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I have searched around and could not find a fix for this issue. Xampp was working fine yesterday but did not start today. So, what I did yesterday was to clone a wordpress website to my pc using xcloner. After I cloned the website, everything was working fine. Then, I stopped mysql and apache and shutdown my pc. This morning, I got that issue.

I had face the same issue other times and I have reinstalled xampp and wordpress (bitnami versions). However, I keep getting that problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the second one of these in as many days. Do you stop XAMPP before you restart or turn off windows?

Comment: Did you run `>aria_chk -r` on all aria tables, like the message suggested?

Comment: You have mariadb, not mysql installed. Mysql does not have aria storage engine, so this question is not applicable to mysql.

Comment: @Shadow I think I fixed all the `MySQL` bits to `mariaDB`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, i did shot it down before turning it off. How do I run aria_chk -r?

Comment: I would start by looking in the [mariaDB Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/aria_chk/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have looked at this documentation already but aria_chk is not recognized by Windows cmd (terminal). I will keep looking around.

Comment: Look in the `mariaDB\bin` folder thats where ALL these little utility programs live

Comment: Run it? How and on which database files?

Comment: @RiggsFolly wait a moment, I will double check something in aria tables.

Comment: @RiggsFolly its working! I will post an answer. Thank!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

With the help of @RiggsFolly, the following solved my issue.

1. Open cmd.
2. In cmd, go to `xampp/mysql/data folder`.

   - In my case, I did the following `cd C:\xampp\mysql\data`
3. Run `aria_chk -r` in that directory for all `.MAI` tables in the mysql subfolder.

   - In my case, `..\bin\aria_chk -r mysql\*.MAI`
4. Delete all `aria_log.########` files. They are present in the C:\xampp\mysql\data folder. I just renamed them for just in case (added `old_` in the beginning of their names).
5. Start xampp again and it should be working.

Comment: Does XAMPP really place mariaDB into a folder called `mysql`? No wonder people get confused :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - MariaDB is a spinoff of MySQL; some things ("mysql", "mysqld") have not been changed.  This is partially to make it a "drop-in replacement" for MySQL.

Comment: @RickJames Hi Rick, I know. However it does add to the level of confusion, specially now that with every new release of MySQL the 2 get less and less alike. :)

Comment: @Hugo Fernando Maia Milan do you have to run this command everytime for xampp to work or have you found a permanent solution to this I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853374/xampp-mysql-not-starting-v3-2-4) about it

Comment: @NishaDave not every time, only when it was not working. If I remember correctly (I'm not actively using XAMPP at this time), turning Windows off without closing XAMPP might lead to this problem. Maybe that's worth a try.

Comment: @Hugo Fernando Maia Milan : Thanks this works for me.

Comment: It is not working for me. When I run the command `aria_chk -r mysql\*.MAI` a separate windows pop-ups with a message that `aria_chk.exe has stopped working`. Any other solution for this?

Comment: @Mohal: I don't know how to go about it. Maybe it's worth to open another question.

Comment: Simply deleting `xampp\mysql\data\aria_log.#######` solved the problem in my case.

Comment: Running this command C:\xampp\mysql\bin\aria_chk -r mysql\*MAI fixed it for me. I did not have to delete anything.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with the solution of answer 1, it look great but in my case from cmd I got an error of permission denied for files xampp\mysql\data\mysql*.mai.
Instead I found another solution.

**ATTENTION**: the drawback is that you lose the users created with database privileges, in my case it is not a big damage because I only had four sites locally, and it was easy for me to recreate the users in phpmyadmin.

The whole tour takes 5 minutes and you work on the folders and files, even without cmd:

1. delete all xampp\mysql\data\mysql.mai files
2. copy all .mai files from mysql backup folder: xampp\mysql\backup\mysql*.mai
3. delete the aria_log.######## files in the xampp\mysql\data folder
4. restart xampp: It works!
5. recreate the privileged users of each database in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Simply deleting "xampp\mysql\data\aria_log.#######" was enough for me.

Comment: @Fastnlight despite the appearance, this is not really a thank you answer. it's saying that a smaller subset of existing answers is all that was necessary for them. that's potentially useful information, and is just fine as an answer post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to delete file `multi-master.info` in `xampp\mysql\data`

Solution comes from thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/62957955/269804