# xampp mysql Failed to initialize multi master structures

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed xampp on windows and it worked.

Today when i try to start mysql service it returns this error and i can't run mysql

```
2020-01-05 17:10:07 17 [Note] Master '2020-01-04 19:28:32 23 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\htmarket\users'
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d01@002d04@002019@003a28@003a32@002023@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020checking@0020table@003a@0020@0020@0020@0027@002e@005chtmarket@005cusers@0027@000d.000012' position: 4
2020-01-05 17:10:07 16 [ERROR] Master '2020-01-04 19:28:32 23 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\htmarket\users'
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2020-01-05 17:10:07 0 [Warning] Reading of some Master_info entries failed
2020-01-05 17:10:07 16 [Note] Master '2020-01-04 19:28:32 23 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\htmarket\users'
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
2020-01-05 17:10:07 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
2020-01-05 17:10:07 16 [Note] Master '2020-01-04 19:28:32 23 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\htmarket\users'
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2020-01-05 17:10:07 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

what's wrong with mysql?

Answer (score 44):

If it helps, I had the same issue and I could fix it by deleting all the files mysql misteriously generated in data directory:

[image]

Just delete all the master files and leave your data folder like this picture:

[image]

Hope this helps. Cheers!

EDIT - After deleting all those files, each time I try to start Mysql again, I need to delete **aria_log.00000001** (this number increments each time I start Mysql). Keep that in mind if it's happening the same again.

Comment: This works in my case. I'm not sure what the masters files do, but I don't need them as long as I can access my data.

Comment: This helped me when not much else would. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was about to reinstall xampp, which is a pain when you have loads of databases and sites, but luckily I found this answer before it!

Comment: I just posted about the same issue but for some reason my question was moved to Database Administrators. A word of warning I tried deleting the files indicated and MySQL ran fine the first time but not the second time. The safer option may be a reinstall.

Comment: Reinstall fixed it. A fresh reinstall of XAMPP adds the file 'multi-master.info' which on inspection is blank so either don't delete this file or try erasing its contents if you have a backup.

Comment: The first thing I tried was to reinstall XAMPP, but it didn't work for me at all

Comment: @Daniel Vivas you're correct. it's three weeks since I posted and I just discovered the files are back. This feels like an issue with the XAMPP installation as none of us have enabled replication. Now we have Windows Subsytem for Linux I will look into installing LAMP and see if it resolves the issue in which case XAMPP won't be necessary.

Comment: This fixed my sql crashing every 2 months for no reason, thanks!

Comment: This actually fixed it for me too, thank you!

Comment: Most Importantly Delete **aria_log_control** file if you want to avoid manually deleting of **aria_log.00000001++** files on each restart

Comment: I had to delete (move) every file from the /data directory except my.inim, ibdata1, ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1 to make MySQL work.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue, just delete the multi-master.info and all the garbage it created after the error and restart the mysql.

It worked for me.

Comment: This is what worked for me too. What I don't understand is how all those files got there in the first place. I don't use Replication (master->slave) stuff. And those files are not on my other computer, which uses this same version of XAMPP/PHP7/MariaDb . This started happening AFTER the most recent Windows 10 update (November 10, 2020). Since I haven't changed anything in the mysql directory since it was installed on this laptop, nor have I changed anyting in Apache, I'm blaming this on Windows 10.

Comment: When I deleted those files mentioned above, mysql started fine. Then I discovrded that none of the innodb tables are recognize -- "Table doesn't exist in engine" message occured on all innodb tables. The myisam tables are ok.

Comment: EDIT: 04-16-21 This happened again, and **again** it happened after a 'forced' Windows 10 Update (i.e., the system automatically rebooted overnight even tho I thought I had it on "Pause".) So this time, I simply blanked out the contents of multi-master.info & left it blank. I didn't delete those other 'garbage files', but simply rebooted Windows & then started XAMPP, Apache, then MySQL. Everything successful, and no problems with innodb this time. Simple fix. Now if we can just get MS to stop forcing reboots on our machines.

Comment: 01-24-2022 -- This error happened again, and it was (again) after another forced Windows 10 update. I simply blanked out the contents of the multi-master.info file, restarted Windows 10, then started XAMPP and it all worked fine just as I noted in my previous comment of 04-16-21. MICROSOFT NEEDS TO STOP FORCING UPDATES WHEN WE HAVE THOSE ON 'PAUSE'!!

Answer (score 21):

I had same issue and just delete multi-master.info, then it worked for me.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 10):

i suggest anyone faces this problem to delete multi-master.info in xampp/mysql/data

i had the same problem and when i deleted the file i could start mysql and access my data again

Data will not be deleted don't worry

Answer (score 9):

This issue has been haunting me for some weeks now but I accidentally resolved it without deleting files or reinstalling XAMPP. When I launched XAMPP recently MySQL refused to start with the error message `MySQL shutdown unexpectedly` which I believe may be related to user permissions but that's another issue.

I did a quick Google Search, followed the instructions in [the first hit](https://www.webfulcreations.com/fix-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-in-xampp/) and the issue never returned. The below is a copy and paste of the instructions I followed.

1. Rename the folder `xampp/mysql/data` to `xampp/mysql/data_bk`.
2. Create a new folder `xampp/mysql/data`.
3. Copy the content that resides in `xampp/mysql/backup` to the new
   `xampp/mysql/data` folder.
4. Copy all your database folders that are in `xamppmysql/data_bk` to
   `xampp/mysql/data`.
   **Important**: Do not copy the `mysql`, `performance_schema`, and `phpmyadmin`
   folders from `xampp/mysql/data_bk`
5. Finally copy the `ibdata1` file from `xampp/mysql/data_bk` and replace
   it inside `xampp/mysql/data` folder
6. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

From what I've read I suspect the cause is compatibility issues between MariaDB, PHP 8 and MyPhpAdmin. In future I plan to migrate to LAMP in Windows Subsystem for Linux instead of XAMPP.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, mysql just stopped working and it gave me the same errors you had.

After hours of searching online, and trying many different solutions, the **only thing that worked was reinstalling xampp**.

**If you want to keep your databases**, before you uninstall the old xampp, go to **xampp/mysql/data** and **do a backup** of all the folders/databases you want to transfer to a new install of xampp.

Also, dont forget to do the backup of all **ib** files in the same folder (in my case I had: **ibdata1**,**ib_logfile1**,**ib_logfile2**). If you have anything important in htdocs, dont forget to do the backup of that as well.

After you uninstall, download xampp and install the fresh version, go to **data** folder and rename ib files just in case to have backup, after that copy the old **ib** files and database folders to your newly installed xampp.

Open the xampp control panel as admin, and restart mysql, after that, it should work fine, at least it did for me, and all of my tables and data were still usable.