# Xampp mysql not starting v3.2.4

Tags: php, web, server, xampp

I tried deleting the aria_log_control file

I tried changing the port

I tried deleting aria_log.0000001 file

I tried deleting both aria_log_control and aria_log.0000001 file

I am running the control panel as admin

I also tried restarting my computer multiple times

it was working properly just a day ago though i had to delete aria_log_control file multiple times

.

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-05-01  2:14:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-05-01  2:14:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-01  2:14:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-01  2:14:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-01  2:14:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-01  2:14:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-05-01  2:14:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-01  2:14:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=903140
2020-05-01  2:14:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*50331648 to 2*5242880 bytes; LSN=903158
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x59fa)
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*50331648 to 2*5242880 bytes; LSN=130575462
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=130575462
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 130575462; transaction id 64548
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2020-07-08 21:27:40 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x59fa)
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-08 21:37:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*50331648 to 2*5242880 bytes; LSN=130576423
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-11 23:57:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-11 23:57:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-11 23:57:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-11 23:57:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-11 23:57:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-11 23:57:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-07-11 23:57:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*50331648 to 2*268435456 bytes; LSN=133846091
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 268435456 bytes
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 268435456 bytes
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=133846091
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 133846091; transaction id 66193
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-11 23:57:23 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 133846549; transaction id 66193
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\plugin'
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\servers'
2020-07-11 23:58:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\aria_log.00000001' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 133846558; transaction id 66193
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-12  0:00:22 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 133846567; transaction id 66193
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-12  0:00:29 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 133846576; transaction id 66193
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\plugin'
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\servers'
2020-07-12  0:00:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-12  0:02:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-12  0:02:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-12  0:02:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-12  0:02:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-12  0:02:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-12  0:02:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-07-12  0:02:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
```

Comment: I also often had problems with errors. I recently switched to Linux. That fixed everything for me and I haven't had any problems since then. Windows always had errors. Otherwise, I don't know what that error could be :(

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf].  In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after a lot of research I found my answer in this post so I am linking it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410692/xampp-windows-mariadb-not-starting)
turns out i had to run the `aria_chk` file in bin folder

Answer (score 5):

solved in my case:

In  "c:\xampp\mysql" folder, copy all files in "backup" folder to "data" folder.

enjoy:)

Comment: worked for me, i tried everything else. Not sure what the issue was

Comment: After this copy, I start mysql and all data of all tables of all databases are gone.
But, then I restore ib_data1 and voilá! My data is back! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In "c:\xampp\mysql" folder, copy all files in "backup" folder to "data" folder.

Solved

Answer (score 0):

For those coming back from time to time because of this issue here are some of the fixes summarized:

1. delete/rename aria_log.XXXXXX file
2. copy all files from backup folder to data folder
3. delete all xampp\mysql\data\mysql.mai files and copy all .mai files from mysql backup folder: xampp\mysql\backup\mysql*.mai