# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly (MySQL not starting anymore soon after database dump import)

Tags: mysql, windows, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org) for local website development. I noticed the 2nd time now that MySQL crashes/corrupts itself a while after doing a (big) database import from an SQL file which was created by exporting the database from the server in PHPMyAdmin. In the meantime things worked fine though.

When I try to start MySQL now the error is:

```
12:17:23 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
12:17:23 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
12:17:25 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
12:17:25 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:17:25 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:17:25 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:17:25 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:17:25 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:17:25 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:17:25 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Checking the mysql_error.log shows nothing terribly useful:

```
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 56544792; transaction id 997
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220718  0:17:24
2022-07-18  0:17:24 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

However, checking the Windows Event Viewer under Windows Logs -> Application seems to show the startup failure's culprit:

```
The description for Event ID 100 from source MariaDB cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

mysqld.exe: Error on close of 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\aria_log_control' (Errcode: 9 "Bad file descriptor")



The system cannot find the file specified
```

The gist seems to be the error on close of the aria_log_control file. I don't quite understand this error. The file exists and is not locked. Deleting the file does not fix the issue. Also [deleting aria_log.00000001 does not work](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=265827). How does MySQL's startup even fail for this reason and how does MySQL suddenly fail to start (out of nowhere)? I also tried restarting Windows but the issue didn't get fixed. I'm sure there's no malware on my system causing those issues. Moving/Renaming my database's folder inside `C:\xampp\mysql\data` did not work, also moving/renaming `C:\xampp\mysql\data` directly did not work either. What can I do to avoid this MySQL startup failure and how can I fix it besides a full XAMPP reinstallation? The latter worked to get back up and running with MySQL but it's not a great solution, I'll have to recreate the database, import the schema and the database data itself just for the issue to happen again (most likely).

Answer (score 0):

The error is Windows reporting the file was not opened (perhaps already closed) when attempting to close the `aria_log_control` file.

This is a MariaDB implementation error somewhere, but won't cause any data corruption. It might be possible in some path where [open_files_limit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#open_files_limit) is exceeded.

Deleting control files and restoring from backup won't help. Raising a open_file_limit or the variables it depends on may help. If not, ignore this windows error message for now.

I've created bug report ([MDEV-29117](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29117)) based on this. For reference, about how many tables are in your SQL file. Are these Aria, InnoDB or a mix?

Comment: Hi, I use all defaults, e.g. InnoDB. I'll see about raising the open_file_limit. That sounds like it could help.

Comment: I added `open_files_limit=99999999` to my my.ini configuration file and restarted MySQL but it did not solve the issue either. For too many open files I would expect an error message regarding that and not something unhelpful like what I'm getting with "error on close".

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by deleting all files beginning with 'mysql-relay-bin-' located in the mysql/data directory.

I had attempted to address the problem using the solution suggested in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/59411279 prior, but it was unsuccessful.